# Managing MS Exchange server-side email rules on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, email, exchange, apple-mail

Has anybody found an easy way to manage server-side rules from Mac OS X?

Here's a brief list of what I know doesn't work:

- Entourage 2008 - it supports client rules, but not server rules. No good, there are certain actions that should happen before I open my laptop or check my email on my iPhone.
- Apple Mail - same as Entourage, but at least I don't get as frustrated since, unlike Entourage, this isn't a Microsoft product.
- Web mail (aka Outlook Web Access) - perhaps you can manage rule in the fancy version which Exchange serves to IE, but not with the browsers available on a Mac.

I manage this now by launching a VMWare virtual machine running Windows XP and Outlook. I don't count that as an easy way.

---

**Update, post release of Office 2011**

Does MS Outlook 2011 have the ability to manage server-side rules?

---

**Update, post installation of Office 2011**

No. Outlook 2011 doesn't have this ability.

*I've already removed my account from Outlook and switched back to Apple Mail and iCal*

---

**Update, now on Outlook.com/Office365**

Yes, yes, yes! Outlook 2011 (version 14.3.5) can do this. The web client for Office365 is also much better on mac browsers.

The short answer to my original question is: get your company to update to Office365!

Comment: Outlook 2010 on Winddows can make server-side rules, so I can't see why MS would have excluded that ability from Outlook 2011 on MacOSX.

Comment: And you can also do it via IE on Windows. That means that there's likely a simple API on the server side. There's no good reason why MS wouldn't put a UI within Mac Outlook to communicate with that same API.

Comment: For what it's worth, I usually manipulate rules now by using [CoRD](http://cord.sf.net) to make a remote desktop connection to a windows machine and then connect to Outlook Web Access using IE.

Comment: This should belong to http://apple.stackexchange.com - still there is no flag option for moving it to this SE site.

Comment: @Sorin - I don't see how this is off-topic on Super User? Unless it's off-topic here, or the traffic is near-zero and the OP isn't getting help, there's no reason to migrate this away.

Comment: @Sorin - additionally, when I asked the question, apple.stackexchange.com wasn't yet live.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, changing server-side rules from pure OSX is not possible. When our Mac users request this at work, we help them through setting up the rules in a full Outlook client. Microsoft hasn't exposed these APIs to non-MAPI clients, and as you've already discovered the non-IE OWA doesn't have this support either.

The IE OWA version can do rules (at least in Exchange 2007 and higher), but even that functionality is somewhat reduced. But Server-side rules (folder sorting and the like) are able to be created.

Comment: From what I have heard OWA from Exchange 2010 works on non-IE browsers just as well as IE (although I cannot confirm this, as I am still using Exchange 2007).

Comment: That is not the case paradroid.

Answer (score 2):

Since this question was first asked, Microsoft have released Office 2011 service pack 1.

The editing of server-side rules is supported in Outlook 2011 SP1 when used with Exchange 2010, SP1 (and later). See:

http://www.officeformachelp.com/2011/04/microsoft-releases-office-2011-for-mac-sp1-14-1-0-update/

I can confirm that this works (I use this set-up at work).

Answer (score 1):

With Exchange 2010 Outlook Web Mail works in Safari, Firefox and Chrome and will allow you to edit server-side rules from a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

With Exchange 2010 OWA onwards, Server side rules can be added under Options > Mail > Automatic Processing > Inbox and Sweep Rules > Inbox rules

Answer (score 0):

If you're like me and still looking, this is what their support page says for Mac:
"Important: In the new Outlook for Mac (as of October 2020), only server rules are available, client rules are no longer supported."

EDIT What that means is that **ALL RULES** are *SERVER-SIDE RULES*, at least on the Mac.

This applies to:
Outlook for Microsoft 365 for Mac Outlook 2021 for Mac Outlook 2019 for Mac Outlook 2016 for Mac Office for business Office 365 Small Business
/EDIT

Source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-rule-in-outlook-for-mac-c8fde328-de0d-4579-abc4-564cc8922f71

EDIT: In response to the feedback (which was more than fair!), clarified a bit.

Comment: Link only answer is useless. 
Can you elaborate on this a litle more?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.